# Submitting form with redux form

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form, redux-thunk

I have my own action that I want to use to submit a redux form

`actions/spell.js`:

```
export const updateSpell = (spell) => ({
    [RSAA]: {
        endpoint: '/api/spell/' + spell.id,
        method: 'PUT',
        body: JSON.stringify(spell),
        headers: withAuth({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
        types: [
            UPDATE_SPELL, UPDATE_SPELL_SUCCESS, UPDATE_SPELL_FAILURE
        ]
    }
});
```

But I'm having throuble figuring out exactly how to set up the submit functions.  I've tried various solutions I've searched for online, but they give various errors.

The default action isn't the behavior I want the form to have.  And trying to substitute my own submit function, it either throws errors related to how redux-form should be set up, or I can't figure out how to pass the form values.

Any guidance on how to set up a custom submit function to the redux form?

```
class FormSpellEdit extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            id: 0,
            owner: 0,
            Name: 'NoName',
            School: 'NoSchool',
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.initialize(this.state)
    }

    render() {
        const { classes, submit, handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = this.props;

        const renderTextField = ({
                 input,
                 label,
                 meta: { touched, error },
                 ...custom
             }) => (
            <TextField
                hintText={label}
                floatingLabelText={label}
                errorText={touched && error}
                {...input}
                {...custom}
            />
        );

        return (
            <form
                onSubmit={handleSubmit}
            >

                <Button
                    variant="fab"
                    color="primary"
                    aria-label="Save"
                    disabled={pristine || submitting}
                    onClick={submit}
                >
                    <SaveIcon/>
                </Button>


                        <Grid fluid>
                            <Row>
                                <Col xs={12} >
                                    <CardContent className={classes.spellCardContent}>
                                        <Typography>Spell Name</Typography>
                                        <Divider />
                                        <Field
                                            fullWidth
                                            name="Name"
                                            component={renderTextField}
                                            label="Spell Name"
                                            value={this.state.Name}
                                        />
                                    </CardContent>
                                </Col>
                                <Col xs={12}>
                                    <Divider />
                                </Col>
                                <Col xs={6} lg={1}>
                                    <CardContent className={classes.spellCardContent}>
                                        <Typography>School</Typography>
                                        <Divider />
                                        <Field
                                            fullWidth
                                            name="School"
                                            component={renderTextField}
                                            label="Spell School"
                                        />
                                    </CardContent>
                                </Col>
                            </Row>
                        </Grid>
        );
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
    return {
        errors: authErrors(state),
        user: state.auth.access,
        user_id: userId(state),
        page: {
            spell: state.spell
        },
        initialValues: state.spell,
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        handleSubmit: (values) => dispatch(updateSpell(values)),
    }
};


export default compose(
    connect(
        mapStateToProps,
        mapDispatchToProps,
    ),
    reduxForm({
        form: 'FormSpellEdit',
        enableReinitialize: true
    }),
    withStyles(styles, {
            withTheme: true
        },
    ))(FormSpellEdit);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call your own handler for form submit as follows.
      Let the handle method be

```
handleMethod(data) {
          ...//Submit handling
          console.log(data)
      }

   render() {
    const { classes, submit, handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = this.props;
      ....// your other codes
        return (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleMethod)}>
           .... // your other codes
           )
```

Comment: But what if I don't need to do anything extra in terms of handling it.  I just need it to send it to a custom action on submit (currently just called handleSubmit in the matchDispatchToProps but I can change it)

Comment: you can call the action method as  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.props.handleSubmit)}>

Comment: Ok and just for best practices, I only got it to work when I had the onSubmit in the form tag, but for the save button I had `onClick={handleSubmit(this.props.sendSubmit)}`.  What should I put in the onClick to make it submit the form instead of calling the submit from the button?  I tried just doing `onClick={submit}` but that didn't work.

Comment: you could include a button like  <button type="submit">Save</button> ,which will submit the form